# I can not create a lumen project

Tags: lumen

I have just installed composer and I have added this path where it is "~/.composer/vendor/bin" to my $PATH in OSX. But when I try this in terminal: >lumen new blog I get "-bash: lumen: command not found".

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the project with this other command "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen first app" but I don't know why I can not execute the lumen command